# Form in django not saving in Psql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am new to Django and this is my first project.

I want to allow the user to up/down vote others users post. I have a model.

I am using postgresql as database, and I was able to create users and posts for each users, but when I added in my model Django the following vote fields:

```
upVote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="upvote")
downVote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="downvote")
```

it just stopped saving users post in the database. It does not display any errors  nothing, it

just does not save.

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
from django.conf import settings


class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             default=1,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL
                             )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    images = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='post_pictures/', null=True, blank=True)
    videos = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos/', null=True, blank=True)
    upVote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="upvote")
    downVote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="downvote")
```

In the view.py the login and the registering works, but since I want to display all the post in
the index I see nothing. Bc the DB is empty.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login-page/')
def personalPage(request):
    form = FormPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully created")
    return render(request, 'accounts/personal-page.html', {'form': form})

def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("personalPage")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
                return redirect("personalPage")
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register-page.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('personalPage')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('personalPage')
            else:
                messages.info(
                    request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login-page.html')
```

The url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register-page/', views.registerPage, name='registerPage'),
    path('login-page/', views.loginPage, name='loginPage'),
    path('logout/', views.logOutButton, name='logOut'),
    path('personal-page/', views.personalPage, name='personalPage'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The form template

```
{%extends 'accounts/base.html'%}{% load static %}{%block content%}
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h1>Personal page</h1>
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logOut' %}">LogOut</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}<br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <p>Title :</p>
    <br />
    {{form.title}}
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <p>Movie's extract:</p>
    <br />
    {{form.videos}}
    <br />
    <p>Movie's picture:</p>
    <br />

    {{form.images}}<br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <p>Description :</p>
    <br /><br />
    {{form.description}} <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="Register Account" />
  </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

The index template.

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html'%} {% load static %}{% block content%}
<h1>
  Landing page
</h1>
<!-- Nav bar -->
<section class="index" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="user-post">
    {% for post in posts%}
    <p>{{post.user}}</p>
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    <br /> 
    <p></p>
    <br />
    <p>Videos</p>
    <br/>
    {%if post.videos %} 
    <video width="350" height="200" controls autoplay>
      <source src="{{post.videos.url}}" type="video/mp4"> </source>
    </video>
    {% endif %}
    <br />
    <p>Images</p>
    <br/>
    {% if post.images %}
    <img src="{{ post.images.url }}" width="240px" />
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    {%endfor%}
    <br/>
    <br/>

  </div>
</section>
{% endblock%}
```

The form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, TextInput, ImageField, TypedChoiceField
from . models import UserPost


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class FormPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPost
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'images',
                  'videos', 'upVote', 'downVote']
        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'title', 'placeholder': 'Title'}),
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textarea', 'rows': 10, 'placeholder': 'Description'})}
```

I suspect that my model is not appropriate for Psql. But I am not sure.

Comment: All your fields will work in all supported databases. Because you did not use specific database field .. So the problem not on your model.

Answer (score 0):

After adding new fields to the database you need to make migrations and then migrate so that the new changes can take effect.

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I did several times ```python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate```But it still did not work.

Comment: In your form.py, ```class FormPost(forms.ModelForm): ``` should be ```class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):```. I don't know if this will make a difference but have you tried using a python debugger? This should help you go through your code as its being executed  which can help figure our where your code is not working as expected.